# Special case of OrderBy

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

What does

```
.OrderBy(x => x == somevalue)
```

do? It *sorts* the some value-elements to the end. But *why*?

Code example:

```
var arr = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
var arr2 = arr.OrderBy(x => x == 2).ToArray();
// arr2 --> 1, 3, 2
```

Comment: Its ordering by `bool` (`x == 2` is a `bool` value if x equals to 2), `false < true`

Comment: Alternatively, if you want values that are 2 on the top, use OrderByDescending(x => x == 2) or OrderBy(x => x != 2).

Comment: "I didn't find a reference on the web"? For what? Sorting by a `bool`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are ordering by `bool`, since `x == 2` is a `bool` value (`true` if `x == 2`, `false` otherwise). In case of `bool` (`bool` implements `IComparable<bool>`)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kf07t5s5(v=vs.110).aspx

```
 false < true
```

that's why

```
 OrderBy(x => x == 2)
```

means "first values that are **not** equal to `2` then `2`s".

```
 {1, 2, 3} -> {1, 3, 2}
```

**Edit:** Finally, `OrderBy` is a *stable sorting*, that's why the initial order `1, ..., 3` (`1` before `3`) has been preserved (if you sort the array with unstable sorting algorithm, say, quicksort you can have `{3, 1, 2}` as a result)